How to get response from third party url and fetch data in response in magento2
I am trying to get some response from third party url.
I am adding the steps I have performed.
Step 1: click on one link
step 2: once click on link it is redirect to third party url with some xml request.
step 3: after some product selection from third party url it is return back in adobe site.
step 4: add those selected products in magento with selactable values.
I have done above all steps but once I return back to the third party url, I am getting error like.

main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action
"vendor\AddParts\Controller\Ajax\AddToCart\Interceptor"
{"exception":"[object]
(Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException(code: 0):
Invalid request received at
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/CsrfValidator.php:105)"}


Your controller have to be use HttpPostActionInterface Action [ extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpPostActionInterface ]

@DhavalVaghela , i made changes as per your suggestion, now I am facing erorr in frontend like Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

have you create endpoint API for that? or you can  try this : $this->getResponse()->getRawBody()
